# DRF CBV PUT Fetch internal server error 500

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework, fetch-api

I have User model with list of friends,
when I send PUT/POST request through GUI via link http://localhost:8000/api/users/2
everything works fine..

But when I try to do this by JS using fetch I got 500 internal server error

There is my model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=True, blank=True)
    isPrivate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    askBeforeStick = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    stickersOnBoard = models.ManyToManyField('Sticker', blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(("first name"), max_length=150, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(("last name"), max_length=150, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Email: ' + self.email
```

There is serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'friends','isPrivate', 'askBeforeStick', 'stickersOnBoard']
```

There is url:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'stickers', StickerViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
```

view:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

and js:

```
        function getCookie(name) {
            let cookieValue = null
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== ''){
                let cookies = document.cookie.split(';')
                for(let i = 0; i< cookies.length; i++) {
                    let cookie = cookies[i].trim()
                    if(cookie.substring(0,name.length + 1)=== (name+'=')){
                        cookieValue=decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length+1))
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue
        }
        let csrfToken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        let friendButton = document.querySelector('#friendButton')
        friendButton.addEventListener('click',()=>{
            let friendID = document.querySelector('#friendID')
            friendID = friendID.innerHTML
            let friendUrl = `http://localhost:8000/api/users/${friendID}/`
            
            let userId = "{{user.id}}";
            let url = `http://localhost:8000/api/users/${userId}`
            
            fetch(url)
        .then((resp)=>resp.json())
        .then(function(data){
            let list = data.friends
            if (!list.includes(friendUrl)) {
                list.push(friendUrl);
            }
            const updatedUserData = { friends: list };
            fetch(url,{
                method:"PUT",
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken,
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(updatedUserData),

            })

            .then((resp)=>{
                if (resp.status === 200) {
                    console.log("Friend added successfully!");
                } else {
                    console.error("Unexpected status code: " + resp.status);
                }
            })
            .catch((err)=>{
                console.error("Error:", err);
            });
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            console.error("Error:", err);
        });
        })
```

Only GET method works fine

Log....

```
[24/Oct/2023 09:13:00] "GET /search?email=asd%40asd.pl HTTP/1.1" 

200 3483
[24/Oct/2023 09:13:00] "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 2803
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[24/Oct/2023 09:13:00] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 3822
[24/Oct/2023 09:13:03] "GET /search?email=asd%40asd.pl HTTP/1.1" 200 3483
[24/Oct/2023 09:13:03] "GET /api/users/2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 238
Internal Server Error: /api/users/2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/patryk/Documents/python/stick/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/patryk/Documents/python/stick/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/patryk/Documents/python/stick/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 108, in process_response
    return self.response_redirect_class(self.get_full_path_with_slash(request))
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/patryk/Documents/python/stick/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 87, in get_full_path_with_slash
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: You called this URL via PUT, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining PUT data. Change your form to point to localhost:8000/api/users/2/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.
[24/Oct/2023 09:13:03] "PUT /api/users/2 HTTP/1.1" 500 68510
```

When I set APPEND_SLASH=False in my Django settings, then I got 404 error

After adding trailing slash I got 400 error, then I changed from PUT to PATCH and everything works.

Comment: Please add the full error traceback.

Comment: A 500 error means that there's an unhandled exception in the server code. You'll have to look at server-side logs etc to determine where it's coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Add trailing slash to the row:
`let url = "http://localhost:8000/api/users/${userId}/"`

Comment: Don't work, weird thing is that whenever I change url, in console I still get the same error: PUT http://localhost:8000/api/users/2 500 (Internal Server Error)... where URL is the same without trailing slash

Comment: `PUT http://localhost:8000/api/users/2` should throw the error but `PUT http://localhost:8000/api/users/2/` – shouldn't.
Django explicitly says the same: "RuntimeError: You called this URL via PUT, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining PUT data. Change your form to point to localhost:8000/api/users/2/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings."